# C++ undefined reference to vtable on compile

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

Why do I keep getting an error on compile with this code?

```
#ifndef OPERATOR_H
#define OPERATOR_H
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "Individual.h"

using namespace std;

class Operator
{
public:
Operator();

virtual void execute (Individual* parent);

private:

};
#endif
```

Then in the cpp file I have

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "Operator.h"

using namespace std;

Operator::Operator()
{  

}

void execute(Individual* parent)
{    

}
```

Comment: Give more details on error, what is in `Individual.h` and try to avoid includes in a header file

Comment: What error is being reported, and on which line of code?

Comment: Crap, just realised I needed Operator:: in front of the execute function.

Comment: Yeah stupid mistake due to lack of sleep.
Working now after changing the CPP file
void Operator::execute(Individual* parent)

Answer (score 0):

Define a destructor. The vtable for a class with virtual methods is created in the translation unit that defines the constructor.

In your header, add:

```
virtual ~Operator();
```

And in your source file, add:

```
Operator::~Operator() {
}
```